# Call MVC Controller from AngularJS using JSON in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-http, jsonresult

JsonResult method not calling through [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) call,

I am working on a project that uses ASP.NET MVC, AngularJS  I am calling a mvc controller from AngularJS. I am getting an jsonresult as in the call to a MVC controller from AngularJS .

**this is the result**

```
[
  {
    "Branch_ID": 1,
    "Branch_Name": "sdsds",
    "Branch_Address": "sfsdfsdf",
    "Branch_email": "sdfsdfsdf",
    "Branch_Notes": "sfsffsfd",
    "Branch_Manager": null,
    "Branch_Phone": null,
    "Branch_TimeFrom": "/Date(-2208996000000)/",
    "Branch_TimeTo": "/Date(-2208996000000)/",
    "saturday": false,
    "sunday": false,
    "monday": false,
    "tuesday": false,
    "wednesday": false,
    "thursday": false,
    "friday": false,
    "Departments": null
  }
]
```

**branches controller**

```
public class BranchesController : Controller
   {

    private IRepositoryBase<Branches> BrancheRepository;

    public BranchesController(IRepositoryBase<Branches> brancheRepository)
    {
        this.BrancheRepository = brancheRepository;
    }
    // GET: Branches
    public JsonResult Index()
    {

        var branches =   BrancheRepository.GetAll();

        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        //{
        //    branches = branches.Where(s => s.Branch_Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
        //}

        return Json(branches, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="branch-controller">
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Branch Details - Grid CRUD operations
    </div>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead style="background-color:lightblue;">
            <tr>
                <th> Branch Address</th>
                <th> Branch Email</th>
                <th>Branch Name</th>
                <th>Branch Notes</th>
                <th> Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="branche in Branches">
                  <td>{{branche.Branch_ID}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_Address}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_email}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_Name}}</td>
                <td>{{branche.Branch_Notes}}</td>

                <td style="width:200px;">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Update</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Module.js**

```
 var myapp;
 (function () {

   myapp = angular.module('my-branches', []);
  })();
```

**Controller.js**

```
myapp.controller('branch-controller', function ($scope, branchService) {

//Loads all branch records when page loads
loadBranches();

function loadBranches() {
    var BrancheRecords = branchService.getAllBranches();

    BrancheRecords.then(function (data) {
        //success

        $scope.Branches = data;
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Error occured while fetching branche list...");
    });
    }
  });
```

**Service.js**

```
myapp.service('branchService', function ($http) {

    this.getAllBranches = function () {

        return $http.get("/Branches/Index").then(function (response) {

            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: What's the issue? You cannot hit action, or you get response but cannot display it?

Comment: @Alexander i get response but i cannot display it,    it is display like this   `[{"Branch_ID":1,"Branch_Name":"sdsds","Branch_Address":"sfsdfsdf","Branch_email":"sdfsdfsdf","Branch_Notes":"sfsffsfd","Branch_Manager":null,"Branch_Phone":null,"Branch_TimeFrom":"/Date(-2208996000000)/","Branch_TimeTo":"/Date(-2208996000000)/","saturday":false,"sunday":false,"monday":false,"tuesday":false,"wednesday":false,"thursday":false,"friday":false,"Departments":null}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to change you code as it is shown [in @georgeawg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59347586/7775908) and then your remaining problem is that you are using invalid property names. The result should look like this

```
<td>{{branche.Branch_Address}}</td>
<td>{{branche.Branch_email}}</td>
<td>{{branche.Branch_Name}}</td>
<td>{{branche.Branch_Notes}}</td>
```

Comment: Still have the same problem after changing the code with property names

Comment: i am still have the same problem please advice

Comment: @hashim Have you tried to debug your js code? Add `debugger` keyword before this line `return response.data;` and inspect what data `response` contains

Comment: `VM246:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined` i have this error

Comment: @hashim Please update your questions with your current code, I'll try to figure out the problem

Comment: @hashim Try add this code at the beginning of `branch-controller` and remove `loadBranches()` call for now

`$scope.Branches = [{"Branch_ID": 1}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204409/discussion-between-alexander-and-hashim).

Answer (score 0):

Change the service call to:

```
var BrancheRecords = branchService.getAllBranches();

BrancheRecords.then(function (data) {
    //success
    $scope.Branches = data;
},
  function (error) {
    console.log(error);
    alert("Error occured while fetching branche list...");
});
```

Change the service to:

```
myapp.service('branchService', function ($http) {

    this.getAllBranches = function () {

        return $http.get("Branches/Index").then(function(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    };
});
```

The data is assigned to the `data` property of the response object.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)

Comment: Still have the problem after change my code to your code

Comment: i am still have the same problem please advice

Comment: i didn't fixed this bug please advice